# How to effectively load in dataTable an XML string that contains html string in its nodes. asp.net 4.0

Tags: asp.net, xml

I want to load XML in a single table of a dataset. I use following code

```
string val = getAbonentInfoParametr(ai,"abonentDescription");
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            ds.ReadXml(new StringReader(val));
```

but when I do this, I got three tables because in one node of XML file I now get HTML code that I want to have like a string field in my only table. What should I do?
Also I prefer not to use scheme files because the structure of that xml file can be changeable except several field that I use, please suggest me something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [CDATA](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_cdata.asp) to wrap around the HTML, otherwise there is no way to differentiate HTML from XML.